# Teams API: Create meetings from a single account between 2 people without an account

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to create a site connecting an individual and a professional via video. Everyone will have an account on my site but not a Microsoft account.

I would therefore need to integrate the Teams API on my site, be able to create meetings from my Microsoft account but for these meetings to be accessible by the client and the professional only without them needing to have or connect to a Microsoft account and without me having to intervene to start the meeting.

In stages this gives:

- The client and the professional make an appointment (date and time)
- The site creates a meeting at the agreed date and time
- The client and the professional receive a link for the meeting or have access to the link from their account (from my site)
- At the time of the meeting they click on the meeting link and open a video together

Is this possible with the Teams API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact requirements, Azure Communication Services is probably a good fit for this. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/